# Could we use zookeeper as a monitoring app?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have a single server instance in the cluster which has got some special duties and we can have only one such server in the cluster. I would like to monitor the health of this server and bring up another instance if this node fails and make the new node join the cluster. Do you think Apache zookeeper can do the job? Could you point me to an example?

Comment: This might help get you started: http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/recipes.html#sc_leaderElection